# while loop needs to continue

Tags: java, while-loop

I have this code

```
static String sCurrentLine = null;

 /* keyword */
static String keyword = null;

 Scanner keywordFile = null, siteFile = null;
           try {
             keywordFile = new Scanner(new File("/home/mearts/keywords.txt"));
             siteFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()));
             sCurrentLine = siteFile.nextLine().trim();
             keyword = keywordFile.nextLine().trim();

               while (sCurrentLine != null){
                 while (keywordFile.hasNext() || keyword == null) {
                 System.out.println("Line--> " + keyword);
                 System.out.println("Current here >>" + sCurrentLine);
                   if (sCurrentLine.contains(keyword)) {
                       System.out.println("Found it-->> " + keyword);
                       keyword = keywordFile.nextLine();
                       System.out.println("next keyword " + keyword);
                       ///* reset search to top of site file */
                       siteFile = new Scanner(new 
                         FileReader(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()));
                         sCurrentLine = siteFile.nextLine().trim();
                   }
                   else {
                     sCurrentLine = siteFile.nextLine();
                     if (sCurrentLine == null) {
                       break;
                     }
                     if (!sCurrentLine.matches(keyword)){
                     System.out.println("The following keyword " + keyword + " does not exist in file "
                         + fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                     }
                   }
                }  //2nd while loop
               }
           }
           catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
          }
           siteFile.close();
           keywordFile.close();
    }
```

and i have a text file called keywords which has a list of keywords in it,
but my logic is off an I cannot figure out why.
I think I may need to run the loop one last time but not sure how to do that
My issue is that the last word in the keyword file never gets read in. so the program stops at the 2nd to last element in the text file.

Comment: Why in your inner while loop do you check for keyword == null ?

Comment: I thought that if keyword was null the loop would exit

Comment: You only need the first part of the or statement keywordFile.hasNext()

Comment: Variable-name prefixes like the `s` in `sCurrentLine` are not compliant with the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Why in the `while` loop do you check for `keyword == null ` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand what your code should do.

If I understood correctly your code, your task is to read keywords from a file with keywords and then find all keywords in another file. Is it correct?

You should separate reading keywords from the file and search for them in the file. You should 'load' keywords in a list and then search through the file.

To load keywords in list

```
keywordFile = new Scanner(new File("/home/mearts/keywords.txt"));
List<String> keywordsList = new ArrayList<>();
while (keywordFile.hasNextLine()) {
    keywordsList.add(keywordFile.nextLine());
}
```

And to search for keywords in the file

```
siteFile = new Scanner((Readable) new FileReader(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()));
while (siteFile.hasNextLine()) {
    String sCurrentLine = siteFile.nextLine().trim();
    for (String keyword : keywordsList) {
        if (sCurrentLine.contains(keyword)) {
            System.out.println("Found it-->> " + keyword);
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(
            "The following keyword " + keyword + " does not exist in file " + fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
}
```

I hope this will help :)

Comment: yes thank you, but the String keyword, seems to contain no data

Comment: @chris, do you mean that `keyword` is `null`? That can happen if the list contains a `null` element. Or do you mean something else by "seems to contain no data"?

Comment: Yes it had a null element. thanks
I am trying to figure out is there a way to use the split(\\.) to remove periods in this line   String sCurrentLine = siteFile.nextLine().trim();